# Can’t find Library or Project Excel VBa

Tags: vba, excel

I’ve run into an issue with a couple of workbooks where the message “Can’t find library or project.”. However, when I open the VBA window to check the references, it’s non responsive (as in I can click things, but no menus appear, the project window displays the desktop, and Active X controls are non responsive).

I’m in Excel 2013. Is it possible that if the file was created in 2010 and brought over there could be issues? I’m acratching my head as this seems to happen completly at random.

Comment: Did you add the reference to the project in `Tools > References`?

Comment: Try opening Excel in safe mode and then checking the references. I think you hold ctrl down when opening Excel but google-fu should tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I managed to open the file in Safe Mode, and tried compiling the code. I believe that there was an error in the Workbook Open code that it may have been corrupting on. I deleted this, and it seems to be all good